# segmentation fault (Core dumped) error Access elements in dynamic array

Tags: arrays, pointers, char, dynamic-arrays

I want to take a string from the user prints it out, and access its  first character, but with below code I get

> segmentation fault (Core dumped)

***Code***

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

 #define GROW_BY 10

int main(){
   char *str_p, *next_p, *tmp_p;
   int ch, need, chars_read = 0;
   if(GROW_BY < 2){
    fprintf(stderr, "Growth constant is too small\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
str_p = (char *)malloc(GROW_BY);
next_p = str_p;
while((ch = getchar()) != EOF){
    if(ch == '\n'){
        printf("%s\n", str_p);  
            //Here is the error I also tried *(str_p + 0), (*str_p)[0]
        printf("%s\n", str_p[0]);
        free(str_p);
        str_p = (char *)malloc(GROW_BY);
        next_p = str_p;
        chars_read = 0;
        continue;
    }
    if(chars_read == GROW_BY - 1){
        *next_p = 0;
        need = next_p - str_p + 1;
        tmp_p = (char *)malloc(need + GROW_BY);
        if(tmp_p == NULL){
            fprintf(stderr, "No initial store\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        strcpy(tmp_p, str_p);
        free(str_p);
        str_p = tmp_p;
        next_p = str_p + need - 1;
        chars_read = 0;
    }
    *next_p++ = ch;
    chars_read++;
}
exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
```

}

Comment: 1) CString must end with NUL character (`'\0'`). 2) `printf("%s\n", str_p[0]);`  : type of `str_p[0]` is `char`, not `char*`. `printf("%s\n", str_p[0]);` --> `printf("%c\n", str_p[0]);`

Comment: Well the error was that I used %s instead of %c

Comment: `printf("%s\n", str_p);` : Besides that, since the character string does not end with NUL, access occurs beyond the valid range. Pointed out in comment (1).

Comment: I have added it and it works great, thx alot guys I feel so dumb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str_p[0]` is a character not string

so you should use **`%c`**

```
printf("%c\n", str_p[0]);
```

This happens because there is no type-safety for the variable arguments, in **`printf()`**,  if the format specifier is wrong, the code will read invalid results from memory, possibly crashing.

One useful tip to help you in debugging is to enable compiler warnings for example in GCC:

```
gcc -Wall main.c -o main
```

this will show you the following warning for your program.

```
warning: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'char' [-Wformat]
        printf("%s\n", str_p[0]);
                ~~     ^~~~~~~~
                %c
1 warning generated.
```

Its highly recommended to use `-Wall` flag to catch some this trouble in your program.

Comment: dont worry You can improve question or your answer! and extends info on it btw i will remove downvote